# How to delete spaces between two words?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, substitution

I have a list of names and I want to create a columns next to each name to post the name correction in the following cases:

- If the name contains "EL" or "AL" and there is a space after both, it is required to to delete that space and concatenate EL or AL with the next word to it such as in the below table :

### [image]

I tried to function

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A2, "Al*","AL")
```

Comment: Please include the formulas you have tried using [edit] and explain what didn't work.

Comment: Your "other condition" is the same as your example for the first condition. Please give proper examples about what you're trying to do here. It doesn't make much sense right now.

Comment: Substitute() can replace the space with blank ie nothing.

Comment: What exactly "If the name contain "El" or "AL" and there is a space after both" does mean? Should them **be**  "El" or "AL", or as you say, something like "UiEl", "AmAL"?

Comment: [This is my attempt for the first two conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U86wB.png). Cannot post it as an answer, because people closed the question. The formula: `=IF(OR(LEFT(UPPER(A1),2)={"EL","AL"}),IF(MID(A1,3,1)=" ",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","",1), SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,2),LEFT(A1,2)&" ",1)),A1)`

Comment: I updated the question as requested. please advise if further correction action is required from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the way you worded your question it seems that both `EL`, `El`, `AL` and `Al` are possibilities. Assuming these substring won't occur on the start of a string and since `SUBSTITUTE()` is case-sensitive, you could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=PROPER(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(G1)," al "," al")," el "," el"))
```

Comment: thank you JvdV , the formula worked. it helped me alot and managed to add more possibilities by using this formula   
   <=PROPER((SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(E5),"al "," al")," el "," el")," seif "," seif")))>    , but for it did not work in case al or el is in the beginning of the sentence , is there an additional fucntion should be nested to the mentioned formula?

Answer (score 0):

This will also work if it's in the beginning:

```
=IFERROR(REPLACE(A2;FIND(" ";A2;FIND("el";LOWER(A2)));1;"");IFERROR(REPLACE(A2;FIND(" ";A2;FIND("al";LOWER(A2)));1;"");A2))
```

I do assume that if a space follows it should be replaced. If you specifically need to check that the space is 2 chars further i would put the "find" part in a helper column.
note: I'm on an EU Excel so you'll probably need to replace the ; with , for the formula to work for you.

best of luck,